# Convert Coordinates of ASC File

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, esri-ascii-raster, lambert-conformal-conic, laea

I am trying to put the Solar Radiation data into QGIS with my current projection of EPSG:27700 but even when I change the projection, the data is well off the mark. The data comes from here: http://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvgis/download/solar_radiation_classic_laea_download.html

The website states the data is in the map projection: Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area, ellipsoid WGS84

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The site you linked mentions these projection parameters:

```
Map projection: Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area, ellipsoid WGS84
Center point: 48° N, 18° E.
```

So you have to build a custom CRS in QGIS. As a reference, search for `lambert` in the list of EPSG codes to find:

```
North_Pole_Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area EPSG:102017
+proj=laea +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

Copy the string to clipboard, goto `Settings -> Custom CRS` tab, paste it into the parameters field, and change the center as needed:

```
+proj=laea +lat_0=48 +lon_0=18 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

Provide a name foor the projection (e.g. `JRC laea`) and hit `OK`.

Now you can drag and drop the asc file to the table of content. But beware, QGIS wrongly assings a false CRS, so rightclick on the layer -> `Set Layer CRS`, and select the custom CRS you just cretaed by searching for its name.

Once done, you can assign the **project CRS** to the same, and add a natural Earth shapefile as a reference:

[image]

Once you found it is correct, you can use `Raster -> Projections -> Warp` to reproject to any other CRS. Make sure you provide the `source SRS` **and** `target SRS`, because gdalwarp is an external command, and does not know what CRS you have assigned to the asc file inside the QGIS GUI. The asc file itself has no SRS information, like Geotoff or other formats have.